# Carrierwave not deleting versions from S3, only the original file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Well, I'm using carrierwave and generating versions (thumbnails) with it. 
The storage backend is Amazon S3.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :attachment, ImageUploader
end
```

When I call Image.find(1).destroy, the original file is removed from S3:

https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/9e966591195c64636825d3ea695f0fc3/61bf4c0c-f9f8-4d29-b794-7daf6d050446.jpg

but a version of it stills there:

https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/9e966591195c64636825d3ea695f0fc3/61bf4c0c-f9f8-4d29-b794-7daf6d050446_square.jpg

I'm suspecting of the method `def full_filename(for_file)`

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  def store_dir
    "assets"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/images"
  end

  version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
    def full_filename(for_file)
      ext         = File.extname(for_file)
      base_name   = for_file.chomp(ext)
      [base_name, version_name].compact.join('_') + ".jpg"
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would also recommend reading the official CarrierWave Github page at: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your version definition as below:

```
version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
 end
```

You do not need to define the file name as Carrierwave will make a new version of file with `square_` prefix. So, its unique anyway.
When you call `Image.find(1).destroy`, Carrierwave destroys the original file and then looks for  a file with `square_*` prefix to delete.

Comment: did you mean to say `You do NOT need to define the file name...` Please fix it.

Comment: @Luccas Please check the updated answer and let me know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: @Luccas Please accept the answer if it worked for you as it will help others to ascertain that the suggested solution resolved your issue.(and indirectly me too :) )